# Can j_security_check authentication be followed by another web authentication mechanism?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jaas, j-security-check

In my web app, I am using form-based login. I have a scenario where I have to validate the users present in a different database in addition to the data of the table set in login-config.xml.

So,I was thinking of this flow:

User tries to access a secured resource -> if No active session,will be redirected to login form -> User enters his credentials -> j_security_check authenticates as per login-config.xml -> if authentication succeeds, well and good, else redirect to a jsp error page, **where I check if the user is present in the other DB(Active directory to be specific.I already have the code to validate the credentials) and create a session on success** -> else redirect to error page

Is the part highlighted above in bold possible at all??

I have read in some articles that  once the authentication is given to j_security_check, there is no way to over rule it. Is it true???

Is there any other possible solution for this problem (apart from adding the users from other db to the table specified in the login-config.xml or modifying the login-config.xml)??

(I am using Jboss)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Servlet Filter that would catch URL to which user is redirected after j_security_check. In this filter check user credentials in the other database.

If the check is succesful add to session boolean value that would reflect that fact. If the check fails remove session (HttpSession.invalidate() method) and redirect user to the error page.

Probably the filter would catch all URL-s that need authorization. In you filter check if there is boolean flag, so you don't do the database check again and again.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Piotr Kochanski.
I have tried an alternate probably not the best of solutions.
What we did was the following:

j_security_check tries to validate the user against my local db.
Since the user is not present, proceeds to the error page.Here I replaced the error page with a servlet, where I check the user in the other DB and if he is a valid user, I am creating an entry in my local DB and then forwarding these credentials to j_security_check again. Now that the entry is present, user is allowed access.